# Django CreateView: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: django

I'm trying to use django's `CreateView`, but I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/PycharmProjects/gusta/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, DeleteView, DetailView, UpdateView
from .models import Employee, Event, detailEvent, Department, Poste
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy

# -----------------------------------------------------  Views for postes.
class PostelistView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "postes/post_list.html"
    context_object_name = "Poste"

    def get_queryset(self):
        # initial queryset of leads for the entire organisation
        queryset = Poste.objects.all()
        return queryset


class PosteCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "postes/post_create.html"
    form_class = "Poste"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("employee:post_list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        self.Poste = instance
        return super(PosteCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

my models.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Poste(models.Model):
    intitule = models.TextField(_("Name"), max_length=250, default='')
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PosteCreateView`, you set

```py
form_class = "Poste"
```

This isn't a class, its a string. [Django expects it to be a class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class) and will later try to instantiate an object. You can see this in the error message, which gives you the line where the exception occurs:

```py
return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

To solve it, set `form_class` to the actual class:

```py
form_class = Poste
```